# Answers marked as read after reading inbox v.s. after reading answer

Tags: discussion, global-inbox, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can we get an option to stop the global inbox from marking everything as read?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72440/can-we-get-an-option-to-stop-the-global-inbox-from-marking-everything-as-read)

When reading inbox programmatically using the json feed (https://stackoverflow.com/inbox/genuwine), answers and comments are marked as read after opening the inbox URL rather than after opening the URL of the actual answer or comment.

For instance if I run a script counting the number of unread messages from the json feed, it will tell me I have e.g. 2 unread posts and if I run this same script once more, it will tell me I have 0 unread posts.

This seems like an odd behaviour if you ask me: why not observe the same behaviour as with a mail inbox i.e. marking posts as read, when they in fact have been read?

Comment: The only thing that JSON route is used for is actually *displaying* the inbox, thus marking as read. If you use it for anything else, that's certainly not a supported use case. Have you looked [at the API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/inbox-unread), by the way?

Comment: I've looked at the python API, but could not find a means to read / count unread messages with it, hence I opted to read json from script as advised in this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104077/is-there-a-global-user-id

Comment: The "Python API"? Not sure what you mean by that. Anyway, being able to read the inbox via the API [is pretty new](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/12/stack-exchange-api-v2-0-public-beta/), so check it out. And again, if you hijack an unsupported API like `/inbox/genuwine`, you shouldn't have any expectation about existence or lack of side effects.

Comment: I meant this API: http://stackapps.com/questions/198/py-stackexchange-an-api-wrapper-for-python
Also I realise v.2 has come out with authentication and all, I will take a look at it. Thanks.